# boolean field not updating in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I am building a basic crud app; with my controller method for updating a `task` as follows :-

```
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to task_url(@task), notice: "Task was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

`Tasks` have a boolean field `completed`.

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "content"
  t.string "createdby"
  t.datetime "createdat", precision: 6
  t.boolean "completed"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Issue is when I am trying to update tasks, **all fields apart from `completed` gets updated**.
Updating `completed` to false gives me `Task updated message` successfully, but value of the boolean field reverts back to `true` no matter how many times I change it.

P.S. I am passing in field `completed` as params.

Below is the view for rendering the checkbox for boolean field `completed` :-

```
<div class="form field-group">
    <%= form.check_box :completed, { class: "class-name", style: "style"}, "checked-value", "unchecked-value" %> Completed
</div>
```

I am totally new to ROR & any help would be appreciated.

Tried updating task from console as follows  :-

`=> Task.last.update(:completed => false).save`

Does update, but reverts back to `true` everytime update is done from browser ui

Comment: What does `task_params` method in your controller look like? You need to add `completed` to its permit list as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the params being sent to the controller when updating?  It would be useful to see two scenarios.  When updating it to set it to false, and then updating it after it has been set to false, when it reverts back.

Comment: Here is my `task_params` method in the controller file
```def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :content, :createdby, :createdat, :completed)
 end```
@ChaseMcDougall @RockwellRice

Answer (score 1):

Your values for the checkbox appear to be `"checked-value", "unchecked-value"` so when it is checked it returns a string of either `"checked-value"` or `"unchecked-value"` Since they are both strings they evaluate to `true`. Change them to `true` and `false`.

```
    <%= form.check_box :completed, { class: "class-name", style: "style"}, "true", "false" %> Completed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form.check_box :completed, { class: "class-name", style: "style"}, "checked-value", "unchecked-value" %>
```

When the check box is not ticked your server will receive `"unchecked-value"` as the value for completed. This will still evaluate to true. You can try this by doing the following in the console:

```
> task = Task.new
> task.completed = "unchecked-value"
> puts task.completed
true
```

The default unchecked value is "0" which will give the expected behaviour.

```
> task.completed = "0"
> puts task.completed
false
```

Unless you have a reason for having "unchecked-value" a fix would be just to use the defaults:

```
<%= form.check_box :completed, { class: "class-name", style: "style"} %>
```